# Unexpected result in byte representation of a variable

Tags: c++, c, casting

I scan through the byte representation of an int variable and get somewhat unexpected result.

If I do

```
int a = 127;
cout << (unsigned int) *((char *)&a);
```

I get 127 as expected. If I do

```
int a = 256;
cout << (unsigned int) *((char *)&a + 1);
```

I get 1 as expected. But if I do

```
int a = 128;
cout << (unsigned int) *((char *)&a);
```

I have **4294967168** which is, well… quite fancy.

The question is: is there a way to get 128 when looking at first byte of an int variable which value is 128?

Comment: The char type is signed, sign extension does the rest.  Use `unsigned char` instead.

Comment: Display the values in hex; things will be much clearer.

Comment: `char` isn't *always* signed, but it is in this case.

Comment: The sign bit in your char is being extended to your int-promotion, then cast to unsigned int. Also, the char-ptr will not always get you what you think it will, depending on the endian-ness of your platform. If there is no intention of this being portable, then rock on.

Comment: Avoid casting if possible - it usually ends in tears.

Comment: @Hans Passant if you consider convert your comment to the answer, I'll accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the same reason that `(unsigned int)(char)128` is 4294967168: `char` is signed by default on most commonly used systems.  128 cannot fit in a signed 8-bit quantity, so when you cast it to `char`, you get -128 (0x80 in hex).

Then, when you cast -128 to an `unsigned int`, you get 2<sup>32</sup> - 128, which is 4294967168.

If you want to get +128, then use an `unsigned char` instead of `char`.

Answer (score 0):

`char` is signed here, so in your second example, `*((char *)&a + 1) = ((char)256 +1) = (0+1) = 1`, which is encoded as `0b00000000000000000000000000000001`, so becomes 1 as an unsigned int.

In your third example, `*((char *)&a) = (char)128 = (char)-127`, which is encoded as `0b10000000000000000000000000000000`, i.e., 2<<31, which is 4294967168

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have pointed out, it looks like what's happening here is that you are running into an oddity of [twos complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).  In your last cast, since you are not using an `unsigned char`, the highest-order bit of the byte is being used to indicate positive or negative values.  You then only have 7 bits out of the full 8 to represent your value, giving you a range of 0-127 for positive numbers (-128-127 overall).

If you exceed this range, then it wraps, and you get -128, which when casted back to an `unsigned int` will result in that abnormally large value.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 128;
cout << (unsigned int) *((unsigned char *)&a);
```

Also all of your code is dependent on running on a little endian machine.

Here's how you should probably be doing these things:

```
int a = 127;
cout << (unsigned)(unsigned char)(0xFF & a);

int a = 256;
cout << (unsigned)(unsigned char)(0xFF & (a>>8));

int a = 128;
cout << (unsigned)(unsigned char)(0xFF & a);
```